# Is there fan-made version of gbc-version exclusive pokemon cards?

Tags: pokemon

Are somewhere on Internet available fan-made versions of cards which are exclusive to Pokemon Trading Card Game for GBC? I mean fake cards, which are looking as real-game cards. It doesn't have to be in printing quality, but should be readable on display (but I don't mind if the art is low-quality copy from GBC assets).

I'm searching them for hours, but cannot find any. (Except Imakuni which was AFAIK released as non-gbc card only in Japan, but English fan-made version is easily found.)

**Edit**: in English, of course.

Answer (score 3):

The 3 legendary birds have been made by ILKCMP :

http://ilkcmp.deviantart.com/art/GB-Promo-3-Articuno-285045912

http://ilkcmp.deviantart.com/art/GB-Promo-10-Zapdos-280707984

http://ilkcmp.deviantart.com/art/GB-Promo-2-Moltres-285045429

Comment: Nice, thank you :). (I wonder whether they're collecting all GB cards on the mentioned PokéBeach)